# RHEL : what does "\S Kernel \r on an \m" mean in /etc/issue.net?

Tags: ssh, rhel, banner

If I `cat /etc/issue.net`, it has this inside:

```
\S
Kernel \r on an \m
```

When I use this as the ssh banner, it does not expand and just prints it as it's written.
What is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in the [agetty manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html#ISSUE_FILES).

It would seem that sshd doesn't process those special strings.